# How Google's Gmail app on iPhone disable notifications?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, gmail, apple-push-notifications

My question can seems weird, but I just realize that when I receive a push for a new mail from Gmail app and I open Gmail on a web page, the notification disappear.

Can someone explain me how this is working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004952/how-to-invalidate-an-ios-push-notification-on-ipad-when-handled-on-iphone), though it's not an exact duplicate.

This can be implemented with Apple Push Notifications.

Your server has to maintain for each user a list of device tokens of all the devices belonging to that user (iPhones, iPads, etc...).

When the user reads the message on one platform (whether via a web browser or via a mobile application), you can execute some API call on your server to notify it that the user read the message.

Then your server can send a follow-up push notification to all the devices belonging to that user with "badge"=0 (and without the "alert" and "sound" fields), and the notification will be cleared from the lock screen and app icon.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that they use notifications delivered in the background (they get delivered directly to the app rather than being shown to the user), then use local notifications. Local notifications can be cancelled.

So it would go like this:

- remote notification "there's a new e-mail" delivered in the background
- local notification "new email"
- ...
- you connect to the website
- remote notification "user has seen new e-mail" delivered in the background
- cancel local notification

I've never actually tried to do this, but I suppose that would be the way it works. I'm not aware of any (documented) way to cancel a remote notification directly.