# Remove already sent push notification from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can I remove already sent push notification from users device from server?

As you probably seen apps like gmail have the ability to remove sent notification from user's device whenever they want. They do mostly when you have multiple client and wants to remove one notification when user watched one of them.

How is that possible? Any idea would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invalidate an iOS push notification on iPad when handled on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004952/how-to-invalidate-an-ios-push-notification-on-ipad-when-handled-on-iphone)

Comment: You can use badge see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038680/how-to-clear-push-notification-badge-count-in-ios

Comment: @Eran no, not duplication

Comment: @ShehzadBilal I mean before opening app by user!

Comment: @AmirAbbasKashani I see you posted the same question again, which is not encouraged in SO. Did you try the answer in the question I suggested as duplicate? See also the comment below that answer.

Comment: @Eran The question was how can I remove it before user tap it!

Comment: Do you have any update on this question? I would like to remove the notification form Notification Center when the app is not running. I know WhatsApp for instance does that. But I can only achieve that if the app is in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for clearing out notifications, try setting the badge count to 0.